# c# Webservice Consumed by PHP client

Tags: c#, php, web-services, authentication

What is the best way to create WebService using Visual Studio which can be consumed by PHP  or Java client?
The WebService must require authorization.

I have some expierence in creation of WCF Service with custom authentication (see: http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2013/07/set-wcf-service-authentication-to-use.html )
and I know that PHP programmers have problems to pass credentials.
Are there any methods of protection of WebService that are compatible with PHP world?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is seeking opinions; questions of which do not fit into the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WEB API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) Is Microsoft's Latest technology for Hosting Web Services.

It is compatible with all official Standards. (XML, JSON, REST ) etc.
There is no reason any platform to have any difficulties connecting to such an API.
You can pass data for identification just by initiating a POST request with a JSON Object.

Comment: If you're going that route take a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint and https://odataphp.codeplex.com/ . Authentication is easy, (fine-grained) authorization a bit harder.